# Get price for Paypal using reference number

Tags: php, excel, paypal

I'd like a customer to enter a reference number to bring up a price and then pay this through Paypal.

I'd like to use an excel file, simply putting the different reference numbers in column A, and the corresponding price in column B.

When the customer puts their reference number into Paypal on the website, the price gets called up from the Excel doc and placed into Paypal, and they can proceed with payment.

I've searched a lot, and I'm assuming it is very simple, but some pointers in the right direction would be awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example using jQuery:

```
Ref# <input type="text" id="ref"> <input type="button" value="fetch price" id="but" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-Rf4BadfyCtsvHmO89BUZcbYvNNvZvOT08ALfEzvCsD0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
var prices = {
    'ref1':'4.00',
    'ref2':'5.00',
    'ref3':'10.00'
}
$(function(){
    $('#but').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var ref = $('#ref').val().trim();
        var price = !prices[ref] ? 0 : prices[ref];

        if(!price)
            return alert('invalid ref#');

        return alert("Your price is : "+price);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! That's awesome, and has got me well and truly started!